# Place svg element in specific position direction

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, svg

I would place arrows ( subways) over circles element (stations).

Arrows could have two opposed directions, they should match the paths direction.

Actually I place my arrow on stations.

I have some issues at this level:

- Arrows are not centered on stations position.
- I can't figure how to set the direction of the arrow.

I have the possibility to set data on every station svg element statically if that could help to determine the direction in js code but I don't have an idea what kind of data to add.

So my problem is how to set arrows with the right angle depending on the paths angle, and also be able to choose the inverted angle

```js
 let rect = document.querySelectorAll('#stops > g');
    rect.forEach(elm=> {
      let thisCircle = elm.querySelector('circle');
      const g = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
      let cx = thisCircle.getAttribute('cx');
      let cy = thisCircle.getAttribute('cy');
      let text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
      text.textContent = '⯈';
      text
      g.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${cx},${cy})`);

      g.appendChild(text);
      let svg = document.getElementById("Calque_1");
      svg.appendChild(g)
    })
```

```html
<svg id="Calque_1" data-name="Calque 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="900px" height="900px" viewBox="0 0 775.43 469.98">
    <defs>
      <style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke-width:5px;}.cls-1,.cls-2{stroke:#a15256;}.cls-2{fill:#fff;}.cls-3{isolation:isolate;font-size:42.79px;font-family:ArialMT, Arial;}</style>
      <marker id='mid' orient="auto" markerWidth='2' markerHeight='4' refX='0.1' refY='1'>
      <!-- triangle pointing right (+x) -->
      <path d='M0,0 V2 L1,1 Z' fill="orange"/>
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <title>line</title>
    <path id="path7" class="cls-1" d="M202,67.72,329.33,215.86" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" />
    <path id="path8" class="cls-1" d="M329.35,215.87,449,355" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" />
    <path id="path9" class="cls-1" d="M449,355c41.53,51.11,96.22,63.08,117.9,69.28" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" />
    <path id="path10" class="cls-1" d="M566.86,424.29C655.43,460.48,977.38,391.48,973,536" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" />
    <g id="stops">
        <g id="g3670">
            <circle class="cls-2" cx="129.24" cy="149.78" r="5.58" />
            <text id="text3668" class="cls-3" transform="translate(140.84 114.12)">Station1</text>
        </g>
        <g id="g3700">
            <circle class="cls-2" cx="248.91" cy="288.93" r="5.58" />
            <text id="text3698" class="cls-3" transform="translate(284.5 239)">Station2</text>
        </g>
        <g id="g3750">
            <circle class="cls-2" cx="366.75" cy="358.2" r="5.58" />
            <text id="text3748" class="cls-3" transform="translate(134.96 379.59)">Station3</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

[Angular stackblitz version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-place-arrow-on-station?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Why are you not using a marker instead of text arrow?

Comment: Do you mean use marker to place it at the end of the station's last path ( or at start of next path) by adding marker attribute dynamically ?

Comment: I mean that you are trying to use text where I would use a marker like the one you have in your `<defs>` but you never use

Comment: How will you use the marker ?  ( the marler in the code was for placing arrows on the path when the a subway still in progress but for arrows in top of stations I don't see how to use it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a changing a few comments the OP is asking:

> How will you use the marker ? ( the marler in the code was for placing arrows on the path when the a subway still in progress but for arrows in top of stations I don't see how to use it)

This is a way of doing it. You can change the value of the refX attribute to move it where you need it to be

```css
path{marker-end:url(#mid)}
```

```html
<svg id="Calque_1" viewBox="0 0 800 500">
    <defs>
      <style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke-width:5px;}.cls-1,.cls-2{stroke:#a15256;}.cls-2{fill:#fff;}.cls-3{isolation:isolate;font-size:42.79px;font-family:ArialMT, Arial;}</style>
      <marker id='mid' orient="auto" markerWidth='10' markerHeight='20' refX='6' refY='5'>
      <!-- triangle pointing right (+x) -->
      <path d='M0,0 V10 L5,5 Z' fill="orange"/>
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <title>line</title>
    <path id="path7" class="cls-1" d="M202,67.72,329.33,215.86" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)"  />
    <path id="path8" class="cls-1" d="M329.35,215.87,449,355" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" />
    <path id="path9" class="cls-1" d="M449,355c41.53,51.11,96.22,63.08,117.9,69.28" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" />
    <path id="path10" class="cls-1" d="M566.86,424.29C655.43,460.48,977.38,391.48,973,536" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" />
    <g id="stops">
        <g id="g3670">
            <circle class="cls-2" cx="129.24" cy="149.78" r="5.58" />
            <text id="text3668" class="cls-3" transform="translate(140.84 114.12)">Station1</text>
        </g>
        <g id="g3700">
            <circle class="cls-2" cx="248.91" cy="288.93" r="5.58" />
            <text id="text3698" class="cls-3" transform="translate(284.5 239)">Station2</text>
        </g>
        <g id="g3750">
            <circle class="cls-2" cx="366.75" cy="358.2" r="5.58" />
            <text id="text3748" class="cls-3" transform="translate(134.96 379.59)">Station3</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> How will you use the marker ? ( the marler in the code was for placing arrows on the path when the a subway still in progress but for arrows in top of stations I don't see how to use it)

In this case I would use `marker-start` and I've changed the refX="2

```css
path:not(:first-of-type){marker-start:url(#mid)}
```

```html
<svg id="Calque_1" viewBox="0 0 800 500">
    <defs>
      <style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke-width:5px;}.cls-1,.cls-2{stroke:#a15256;}.cls-2{fill:#fff;}.cls-3{isolation:isolate;font-size:42.79px;font-family:ArialMT, Arial;}</style>
      <marker id='mid' orient="auto" markerWidth='10' markerHeight='20' refX='2' refY='5'>
      <!-- triangle pointing right (+x) -->
      <path d='M0,0 V10 L5,5 Z' fill="orange"/>
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <title>line</title>
    <path id="path7" class="cls-1" d="M202,67.72,329.33,215.86" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)"  />
    <path id="path8" class="cls-1" d="M329.35,215.87,449,355" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" />
    <path id="path9" class="cls-1" d="M449,355c41.53,51.11,96.22,63.08,117.9,69.28" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" />
    <path id="path10" class="cls-1" d="M566.86,424.29C655.43,460.48,977.38,391.48,973,536" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" />
    <g id="stops">
        <g id="g3670">
            <circle class="cls-2" cx="129.24" cy="149.78" r="5.58" />
            <text id="text3668" class="cls-3" transform="translate(140.84 114.12)">Station1</text>
        </g>
        <g id="g3700">
            <circle class="cls-2" cx="248.91" cy="288.93" r="5.58" />
            <text id="text3698" class="cls-3" transform="translate(284.5 239)">Station2</text>
        </g>
        <g id="g3750">
            <circle class="cls-2" cx="366.75" cy="358.2" r="5.58" />
            <text id="text3748" class="cls-3" transform="translate(134.96 379.59)">Station3</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> I should set marker from JS because it depends on station. not all stations have a marker

You can use a class for the path like this:

```css
.withMarker + path{marker-start:url(#mid)}
```

```html
<svg id="Calque_1" viewBox="0 0 800 500">
    <defs>
      <style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke-width:5px;}.cls-1,.cls-2{stroke:#a15256;}.cls-2{fill:#fff;}.cls-3{isolation:isolate;font-size:42.79px;font-family:ArialMT, Arial;}</style>
      <marker id='mid' orient="auto" markerWidth='10' markerHeight='20' refX='2' refY='5'>
      <!-- triangle pointing right (+x) -->
      <path d='M0,0 V10 L5,5 Z' fill="orange"/>
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <title>line</title>
    <path id="path7" class="cls-1 withMarker" d="M202,67.72,329.33,215.86" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)"  />
    <path id="path8" class="cls-1" d="M329.35,215.87,449,355" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" />
    <path id="path9" class="cls-1 withMarker" d="M449,355c41.53,51.11,96.22,63.08,117.9,69.28" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" />
    <path id="path10" class="cls-1" d="M566.86,424.29C655.43,460.48,977.38,391.48,973,536" transform="translate(-200.1 -66.09)" />
    <g id="stops">
        <g id="g3670">
            <circle class="cls-2" cx="129.24" cy="149.78" r="5.58" />
            <text id="text3668" class="cls-3" transform="translate(140.84 114.12)">Station1</text>
        </g>
        <g id="g3700">
            <circle class="cls-2" cx="248.91" cy="288.93" r="5.58" />
            <text id="text3698" class="cls-3" transform="translate(284.5 239)">Station2</text>
        </g>
        <g id="g3750">
            <circle class="cls-2" cx="366.75" cy="358.2" r="5.58" />
            <text id="text3748" class="cls-3" transform="translate(134.96 379.59)">Station3</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

You'll have to keep in mind that is a marker-start.

Comment: is it possible to superimpose marler on top of station circles without superimposing paths on top of stations  ?

Comment: I should set marker from JS because it depends on station. not all stations have a marker

Comment: I've updated once again my answer showing you that it can be done by adding a class to the paths. Please take a look.